# Uniq in awk; removing duplicate values in a column using awk

Tags: bash, awk, unique

I have a large datafile in the following format below:

```
ENST00000371026 WDR78,WDR78,WDR78,  WD repeat domain 78 isoform 1,WD repeat domain 78 isoform 1,WD repeat domain 78 isoform 2,
ENST00000371023 WDR32   WD repeat domain 32 isoform 2
ENST00000400908 RERE,KIAA0458,  atrophin-1 like protein isoform a,Homo sapiens mRNA for KIAA0458 protein, partial cds.,
```

The columns are tab separated.  Multiple values within columns are comma separated.  I would like to remove the duplicate values in the second column to result in something like this:

```
ENST00000371026 WDR78   WD repeat domain 78 isoform 1,WD repeat domain 78 isoform 1,WD repeat domain 78 isoform 2,
ENST00000371023 WDR32   WD repeat domain 32 isoform 2
ENST00000400908 RERE,KIAA0458   atrophin-1 like protein isoform a,Homo sapiens mRNA for KIAA0458 protein, partial cds.,
```

I tried the following code below but it doesn't seem to remove the duplicate values.

```
awk ' 
BEGIN { FS="\t" } ;
{
  split($2, valueArray,",");
  j=0;
  for (i in valueArray) 
  { 
    if (!( valueArray[i] in duplicateArray))
    {
      duplicateArray[j] = valueArray[i];
      j++;
    }
  };
  printf $1 "\t";
  for (j in duplicateArray) 
  {
    if (duplicateArray[j]) {
      printf duplicateArray[j] ",";
    }
  }
  printf "\t";
  print $3

}' knownGeneFromUCSC.txt
```

How can I remove the duplicates in column 2 correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your script acts only on the second record (line) in the file because of `NR==2`. I took it out, but it may be what you intend. If so, you should put it back.

The `in` operator checks for the presence of the *index*, not the value, so I made `duplicateArray` an associative array<sup>*</sup> that uses the values from `valueArray` as its indices. This saves from having to iterate over both arrays in a loop within a loop.

The `split` statement sees "WDR78,WDR78,WDR78," as four fields rather than three so I added an `if` to keep it from printing a null value which would result in ",WDR78," being printed if the `if` weren't there.

<sup>* In reality all arrays in AWK are associative.</sup>

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS="\t" } ;
{
  split($2, valueArray,",");
  j=0;
  for (i in valueArray)
  { 
    if (!(valueArray[i] in duplicateArray))
    { 
      duplicateArray[valueArray[i]] = 1
    }
  };
  printf $1 "\t";
  for (j in duplicateArray)
  {
    if (j)    # prevents printing an extra comma
    {
      printf j ",";
    }
  }
  printf "\t";
  print $3
  delete duplicateArray    # for non-gawk, use split("", duplicateArray)
}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Perl:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane'
  $F[1] = join ",", grep !$_{$_}++, split ",", $F[1]; 
  print join "\t", @F; %_ = ();
  ' infile
```

awk:

```
awk -F'\t' '{
  n = split($2, t, ","); _2 = x
  split(x, _) # use delete _ if supported
  for (i = 0; ++i <= n;)
    _[t[i]]++ || _2 = _2 ? _2 "," t[i] : t[i]
  $2 = _2 
  }-3' OFS='\t' infile
```

The line 4 in the awk script is used to preserve the original order of the values in the second field after filtering the unique values.

Comment: I adapted your **awk** solution to my needs and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I know you asked about awk... but Perl makes this much more simple:

```
$ perl -n -e ' @t = split(/\t/);
  %t2 = map { $_ => 1 } split(/,/,$t[1]);
  $t[1] = join(",",keys %t2);
  print join("\t",@t); ' knownGeneFromUCSC.txt
```

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for the answer.  This solution is better than mine.  However I'm also curious why my solution didn't work.  I will hold of on setting an accepted answer temporarily for that reason.  Maybe someone will know how to do it in awk.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash 4.0 (one associative array):

```
declare -a part                            # parts of a line
declare -a part2                           # parts 2. column
declare -A check                           # used to remember items in part2

while read  line ; do
  part=( $line )                           # split line using whitespaces
  IFS=','                                  # separator is comma
  part2=( ${part[1]} )                     # split 2. column using comma
  if [ ${#part2[@]} -gt 1 ] ; then         # more than 1 field in 2. column?
    check=()                               # empty check array
    new2=''                                # empty new 2. column
    for item in ${part2[@]} ; do 
      (( check[$item]++ ))                 # remember items in 2. column
      if [ ${check[$item]} -eq 1 ] ; then  # not yet seen?
        new2=$new2,$item                   # add to new 2. column
      fi 
    done
    part[1]=${new2#,}                      # remove leading comma
  fi 
  IFS=$'\t'                                # separator for the output
  echo "${part[*]}"                        # rebuild line
done < "$infile"
```