# Print field 2 of file (a) to field 9 of file (b) if fields1 in files (a) and (b) match

Tags: excel, bash, shell, awk

In post [Deduplicate two column file based on minimum value in column 2 AWK / BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249030/deduplicate-two-column-file-based-on-minimum-value-in-column-2-awk-bash)  I have asked for help to produce a file (a) like this:

```
denovo0  90.2
denovo1  97.7
denovo10     93.8
denovo100    95.3
```

The second file (b) has a structure like this (8 columns, tab separated):

```
    denovo1446  1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta; __Metazoa; __Rotifera; __Philodinidae; __uncultured_bdelloid_rotifer
    denovo3423  0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta; __Metazoa; __Nematoda; __Enoplea
    denovo13975 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta; __Metazoa; __Rotifera; __Philodinidae; __uncultured_bdelloid_rotifer
    denovo14362 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta; __Metazoa; __Nematoda; __Enoplea; __Qudsianematidae
    denovo18854 0.0 29.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta; __Metazoa; __Nematoda; __Chromadorea; __Plectidae
    denovo19256 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta; __Metazoa; __Arthropoda; __Hexapoda; __Collembola; __Sminthuridae; __Sminthuridae_environmental_sample
    denovo20076 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta; __Metazoa; __Nematoda; __Enoplea; __Qudsianematidae
    denovo22655 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta;         __Metazoa; __Rotifera; __Philodinidae; __uncultured_bdelloid_rotifer
```

I would like to print field 2 of file (a) to field 9 of file (b) if fields 1 in files (a) and (b) match.

I have looked up similar solutions on StackOverflow, e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140275/match-first-fields-of-two-tab-separated-files-and-print-matching-values, but was not able to adopt them.

My AWK attempts on this failed completely, and I did not come close to a solution. However  I was able to do this in Excel, but this is only possible when the files are small enough:

```
  =INDEX('18S'!B$1:B$692189,(MATCH(phylotypes!A3:A174,'18S'!A$1:A$692189,0)))
```

I index the second field of file (a) for the desired return values, then define the query values in first field of file (b) and match them with the corresponding values in file (a).The "0" ensures an exact match between the "denovo" - strings in fields 1. Furthermore, the "$" symbols prevent "slipping" of the return values when the query values change.

If the files are larger then the ~1 000 000 lines allowed by Excel AWK or BASH will do better.

Kind regards,

Paul

Comment: If `file (b)` has 8 columns then how can you get `field 9 of file (b)` in output?

Comment: This field was meant to be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can se this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {for (i in a) if ($1 ~ i) print $0, a[i]}' fileA fileB
```

**How it works:**

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` - Make input and output field separator as tab
- `FNR==NR` - Execute this block for `fileA` only
- `{a[$1]=$2; next}` - Create an associative array `a` with key as `$1` and value as `$2` and then skip to next record
- `{...}` - Execute this block for 2nd input file
- `for (i in a)` Iterate array `a`
- `if ($1 ~ i)` if key part in array matches `$1` in `fileB`
- `print $0, a[i]` - Print whole record from `fileB` and the value from array

Comment: Plus 1 but you should add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` since he did say it was tab-delimited.

Comment: This works well - example output: `denovo3423 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 Eukaryota; __Opisthokonta; __Metazoa; __Nematoda; __Enoplea 96.9`